# I need to build a matrix of order 2n with input of values, but when I print it something weird happens

Tags: c, matrix

My task is to build a matrix of order 2n with input. But when I'm trying to print it, something strange happens.

Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
    printf("Insert n: \n");
    int n = 0;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Insert the elements of the matrix %d * ", 2*n);
    printf("%d\n", 2 * n);
    int mat[(2 * n) - 1][(2 * n) - 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < 2 * n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2 * n; j++) {
            scanf("%d", &mat[i][j]);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 2 * n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2 * n; j++) {
            printf("%d ", mat[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Insert n:
1
Insert the elements of the matrix 2 * 2
1 2 3 4
1 3
3 4
```

Comment: `int mat[(2 * n) - 1][(2 * n) - 1];` == `int mat[ 1 ][ 1 ];` ... Not big enough for 2x2 = 4 values...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are supposed to declare the 2d array with `int mat[(2 * n)][(2 * n)]`. The number inside squared bracket is the length of the array, not the maximum index.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare any array as having size `int mat[n-1]` then you cannot iterate across it with a `for` loop of the form `(for int i=0; i<n; i++)`. You will access the last item out of bounds.

Proposed fix:

```
size_t size = 2 * n;
int mat[size][size];
...
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
```